# XNA rectangle & contain, going to be crazy

Tags: c#, xna, contain

I'm going to be crazy. In fact, i use Rectangle to know if a point if inside of a rectangle.

My rectangle is define like this : {X:0 Y:480 Width:480 Height:480} 
The point (Vector2) is define like this : {X:283,3333 Y:141,1111}

Normaly, the point is inside of the rectangle ? But not...

```
if (rectangle.Contains(new Point((int)point.X, (int)point.Y)))
{
   return true;
}
return false;
```

With another test, it work with the same code : 
{X:-480 Y:0 Width:480 Height:480} contain {X:-12,22222 Y:12,22223}

Plz, i really need some advices.

Seriously, i don't understand why it don't works !

Comment: But (283,141) isn't inside of (0->480,480->960), while (-12,12) is within (-480->0, 0->480). Code's fine, might want to brush up on your coordinate skills ;)

Comment: The point is really outside the rectangle, check the ys

Comment: Thanks, i really didn't see Y... After 5k lines of codes, you don't see mistakes !

Answer (score 1):

If your rectangle starts at Y = 480, then the point (283, 141) is not in it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but how is the point inside the rectangle?

A simple test to know if a point is inside a rectangle:

```
if ( p.X >= rectangle.X && p.X <= Rectangle.X + Rectangle.Width && p.X >= rectangle.X && p.Y <= Rectangle.Y + Rectangle.Height)
```

The Point (283, 141)  obviously fail the third condition and therefor is not in the Rectangle.

It is however in this rectangle  {X:0 Y:0 Width:480 Height:480}

Comment: Thank you every one. I really don't see the mistakes. I should take some breaks... :p